# How to use IntelliJ's keymap for SublimeText 3

Tags: intellij-idea, sublimetext3, key-bindings, sublime-text-plugin

I'm very used to IntelliJ IDEA's family keybinding (PyCharm, WebStorm, RubyMine...).

How can I configure **Sumblime Text 3** to use those shortcuts?

I've been googling and I can't find anything! But I don't think I'm the only one needing this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Sublime Text 3 - User Key Bindings (IntelliJ IDEA Style) - Windows

```
[
     { "keys": ["ctrl+y"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Delete Line.sublime-macro"} },
     { "keys": ["ctrl+d"], "command": "duplicate_line" },
     { "keys": ["shift+alt+up"], "command": "swap_line_up" },
     { "keys": ["shift+alt+down"], "command": "swap_line_down" }
]
```

found the answer [here](https://gist.github.com/VBourdine/f8068a19303c0ecadf082f4b3a479241#file-default-windows-sublime-keymap).

Comment: Thanks friend, good enough.